# Keycloak phone number verification using Twilio

Tags: java, twilio, keycloak

I would like to customize key cloak resister page with phone number. I would like to use Twilio to send sms. But there is no example anywhere similar to this project."

I have already setup keycloak server and keycloak does not support Twilio.

Please provide me similar project. Thank you.

```
03:59:41,668 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-1) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream
    at six.six.gateway.govuk.notify.NotifySMSService.<init>(NotifySMSService.java:24)
    at six.six.keycloak.authenticator.KeycloakSmsAuthenticatorUtil.sendSmsCode(KeycloakSmsAuthenticatorUtil.java:197)
    at six.six.keycloak.authenticator.KeycloakSmsAuthenticator.authenticate(KeycloakSmsAuthenticator.java:82)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@7.0.0//org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:232)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@7.0.0//org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processAction(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:128)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@7.0.0//org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processAction(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:99)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@7.0.0//org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticationAction(AuthenticationProcessor.java:873)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@7.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processFlow(LoginActionsService.java:296)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@7.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processAuthentication(LoginActionsService.java:267)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@7.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.authenticate(LoginActionsService.java:263)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@7.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.authenticateForm(LoginActionsService.java:324)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but did you look at this plugin: https://github.com/sangyoon-lee/keycloak-sms-authenticator  

Looks like a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

[Dasniko](https://github.com/dasniko) has a good implementation of 2FA with SMS, made using Keycloak's Service Provider Interfaces (SPI)

As I see, you would just need to re-write the `AwsSmsService` into a service using Twilio

https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator

And he also have a youtube video explaining the usage https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQi19817fFk